# When was Harry replaced by the impostor in Significant Other (2022)?

Tags: significant-other

In the climax of the movie *Significant Other* (2022), it is revealed that Ruth had discovered Harry's corpse wrapped up in a cocoon-like structure when she had ventured into the cave.

Based on that revelation, one is supposed to know for a fact that the version of Harry that Ruth has been interacting with after having come out of the cave is an impostor.

Is there any indication in the movie as to when exactly within the chronology of the plot does the impostor take Harry's place?

Answer (score 3):

It happened the morning that Ruth woke up and found the note from Harry saying he was going on a walk to clear his head.

After all, contextual it is the only moment of significant time where they're apart for it to have logically occured. Furthermore, his lack of concern over the deer—not long after—appears to be more about deflection than apathy. Which, being the alien, it would make sense for him to shift Ruth's focus off of the deer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is there that indicates that the replacement happens at this particular time?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the welcome. Contextual it is the only moment of significant time where they're apart for it to have logically occured. Furthermore, his lack of concern over the deer—not long after—appears to be more about deflection than apathy. Which, being the alien, it would make sense for him to shift Ruth's focus off of the deer.

Comment: You should [edit] that into your answer; it's fairly convincing and makes useful evidence.

Comment: Done. Thanks for suggesting that.